# How to replace SimpleRetryStrategy with custom strategy in Rebus configuration

Tags: c#, .net, rebus

Is it possible to replace `SimpleRetryStrategy` with a custom strategy in Rebus configuration?
I don't see the possibility to do this in tests, so does it exist at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that the name `SimpleRetryStrategy` insinuates that there exists multiple retry strategies, but at the moment Rebus does not come with any other strategies than the default "try a number of times (default: 5), then move to error queue" strategy.

It is possible, however, to affect a couple of things around the retries – e.g. you can implement `IErrorHandler` and register your implementation with the injectionist, and then you will get to handle a failed message the way you want instead of the default implementation that moved the message to the error queue.

In the most extreme case, you can replace the entire retry strategy with something else, by registering an `IRetryStrategy`.

Is there some specific behavior you would like in your application?

Comment: I want to skip faulty messages. I.e. serialized can't deserialize some messages, they all dropped to "error" flooding it out.

Comment: you can decorate `IErrorHandler` then – this way you could vary the behavior by simply ignoring the messages you do not care about, while still keeping the messages that are important

Comment: I see that I can event fully replace it. https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/bbb38bcc84be0c2f7c514f113a86a384fbbbebc7/Rebus.Tests/Integration/TestCustomErrorHandler.cs